# Hiding the header and the footer of a section using Eureka forms

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka to create a sign-up page. I have a single section. I would like to hide the header and the footer of the section, and I am not finding a way to do it. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using default section header/footer string settings, you could set them to "" but I believe this will still leave a subtle space where the label/string would usually go.

Your other (probably safer) option may be to create a custom Header/Footer class and sizing it accordingly using the frame properties (width/height = 1px). I have not tested this myself, but I used custom classes to render logos next to labels and size everything to my desired width/height.

Hope this helps.

Option 1:

```
+++ Section(header: "", footer: "") {_ in
    }
```

**Update for Swift 4 and Eureka 4.0.1:**

Option 2:

```
+++ Section(){ (section) in
        section.header = HeaderFooterView<NoHeader>(HeaderFooterProvider.class)
    }

class NoHeader: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -1, width: 1, height: 1))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

Option 2:

```
+++ Section(header: "", footer: "") {
            $0.header = HeaderFooterView<NoHeader>(HeaderFooterProvider.Class)
        }

class NoHeader: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: -3, width: 1, height: 1)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the most efficient way to do it? I found some information about it here: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka. But I don't find the explanation clear, I haven't used nib files before, and if I were to use a class, I don't know how to implement. Can you please give an example?

Comment: @user2840482 I updated my answer above. I tested both and they have the same effect. If you don't need to control the sizing of the blank space held by the "header/footer" then you can just use the first option which keeps everything simple by setting the label properties to null.

Comment: The first one didn't work. The second one worked perfectly well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Option 2 works. It's not necessary to include header:"", footer:"" parameters.

Comment: `$0.header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.class)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add this to your FormViewController:

```
self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If there's documentation on these props please add a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, if your ViewController extend from FormViewController.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```